# Unable to Play Video in Next js App from Flask API (Getting "206 PARTIAL CONTENT" Status)

Tags: python, flask, next.js

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to play video content served by a Flask API in a React app. The Flask API is set up to provide MP4 video files, and when I attempt to play the video in the React app, it doesn't play. Instead, the browser shows a "206 PARTIAL CONTENT" status in the network panel.

Here's the relevant HTML code I'm using in my React component to display the video:

```
<video name="media" style={{ height: "370px" }}>
    <source src="http://127.0.0.1:5000/uploads/signvideo/nJhSsjL3M4s" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Here's the flask endpoint

```
@app.route("/uploads/signvideo/<video_id>", methods=['GET'])
def getSignVideo(video_id):
    print(f"video id {video_id}")
    video_path = os.path.join('videos', video_id)
    videoFile = os.path.join(video_path, f'{video_id}_signVideo.mp4')
    absPath = os.path.abspath(videoFile)
    logger.info(f"sending a sign video id {video_id} abs path {absPath}")
    return send_file(absPath, as_attachment=False)
```

What's particularly puzzling is that when I set the as_attachment parameter to True instead of False in the Flask API response, the video downloads as expected. However, I want the video to play in the next js app.

video file format is MP4 (approximately 100 MB)

how to solve this issue